# Can't play this video error on android videoview from API

Tags: android, api, video-streaming, android-videoview

I want to make streaming video in android apps, but I got an error **Can't play this video** when open my videoView page. In this case I try to get video URL from API and here is my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final PremiumVideo vidx = (PremiumVideo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("video");

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mediaController);

    String url_video = vidx.source_content; // here iam trying to get URL
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_video);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoview.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    });
   }
```

And here is my layout.xml, in this layout that video will played :And here is my layout.xml, in this layout that video will played :And here is my layout.xml, in this layout that video will played :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/iv_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frm_controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="duration"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:alpha=".7"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/grey_e4e4e4">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nama Artis"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtNamaPreview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Judul Video"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtJudulPreview"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Harga"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtHargaPreview"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:text="Subscribe"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_rounded_grey_868686"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The video can be incompatible with your device. Does it play in the built-in video player app?

Comment: I try to play in videoview in my layout xml, and format video is mp4

Comment: **mp4** is too broad. There may be flavors that are not compatible with Android, some can only play on Lollipop+. Some videos play on Samsung, but not Huawei, and so on.